# Pivot Rows To Columns In SQL Server Without AVG or SUM

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table called `tbl_MyTasks` and I need to pivot it so that the below data

**tbl_MyTasks**

```
|  ID  |    Task_Name    |  Task_Description  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1   | Administrative  | Finance Duties     |
|  2   | Administrative  | Meetings           |
|  1   | Development     | SCRUM              |
|  2   | Development     | Coding             |
|  3   | Development     | Code Review        |
|  1   | QA              | Create Test Case   |
|  4   | Development     | Coding             |
|  3   | QA              | User Acceptance    |
```

would be transformed to:

```
|  ID  |  Administrative    |  Development  |        QA         |             
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   | Finance Duties     | SCRUM         | Create Test Case  |
|  2   | Meetings           | Coding        |                   |
|  3   |                    | Code Review   | User Acceptance   |
|  4   |                    | Coding        |                   |
```

So basically I need to group everything by the ID with the `Task_Name` being the new Columns and the `Task_Description` the values for that column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `max()` ?

```
Select *
 From  tbl_MyTasks src
 Pivot (max(Task_Description) for Task_Name in ([Administrative],[Development],[QA] ) ) pvt
```